# ruby regular expression: how to parse key-value pairs?

Tags: ruby, regex

html is string like:

```
<xxx name1 = "value1" name2 = "value2">
```

How to use regular expression to parse key-value pairs into a hash (like `{"name1": "value1", "name2": "value2"}`)? The tag does not matter now.

I am new to ruby and have no idea how to start. Any hints? Thanks

**UPDATE**

My question is how to use regex to do parsing. I know that third party is a good option. But I am just curious about how to use regex to do parsing.

Comment: Don't use regex for this, use an XML parser.

Comment: How to use regex to do it?

Comment: You cannot [parse HTML with regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2483313).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the programming language, parsing html using regexp is not a good idea. In case of Ruby, [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) is a good option.